# Counter word for (western) chess pieces

Tags: counters

If you were counting pieces in chess, say, *one, two, three pawns,* how would you do that in Japanese? Would you use ほん hon, ぽん pon, ぼん bon 本?

I am not sure whether this makes a difference: by counting I mean rather the material value than the actual wooden piece. A better example would be perhaps *3 vs 2 pawns* or counting pieces in computer or online chess.

Comment: Can I make sure if you want to count 1, 2, 3... pawns i.e. counting 1, 2, 3 unit(s) of ポーン is １っぽん、２ほん、３ぼん and so on (using kanji 1, 2, 3本...).

Comment: @kimi Tanaka I added some clarification to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most generic つ or 個 is used to count chess pieces (e.g., 1つ/2つ/3つ... or 1個/2個/3個...). They are not "long and thin" enough to use 本.

By the way, in *shogi*, pieces are flat, so serious players usually count them like 1つ/2つ/3つ or 1枚/2枚/3枚, but 個 is occasionally used by laypeople, too.

The same is true for computer chess/shogi.